# How to pass any anonymous function to ref and use that in other react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref, use-ref

I have 3 functional components and I'd like to pass & manipulate data through `useRef`. 
I am adding this `onClose` method to `current` property in one of my component.

```
const onClose = () => {
    setButtonColor(buttonColor);
};

ref.current = {
    clearSwitchStateOnClose: onClose,  
};
```

I am calling that method in another component.

```
ref.current.clearSwitchStateOnClose();
```

I am receiving this error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: ref.current.clearSwitchStateOnClose is not a function
```

Comment: This question looks like xy problem https://xyproblem.info/. Notice that refs assigned on first render, so you might call your function on mount. Finally, you should just share a reproducible example in codesandbox, refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Inder Notice that you have dedicated API for this. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle

Comment: @DennisVash Got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling this method `ref.current.clearSwitchStateOnClose();` but with that I was also mutating `ref`. I guess that was causing the issue.  
It was something like this,

```
ref.current = {
    showModal: false,
    modalResponse: null,
};
ref.current.clearSwitchStateOnClose();
```

After doing this, it is working fine.

```
ref.current.clearSwitchStateOnClose();
ref.current = {
    showModal: false,
    modalResponse: null,
};
```

Sorry for not sharing the entire scenario of this situation.